# Mysql - Leitura de dados em uma string

Tags: mysql, operadores

Existe uma tabela de Centro de Custo chamada "ccusto", nela, contém IDs (campo "codigo") que gostaria que fosse retornado em um SELECT. O porém é que o dado necessita ser comparado a uma string com separação por virgula, que são os valores que preciso selecionar.

```
Exemplo:
SELECT  codigo
FROM    ccusto
WHERE   codigo  IN('1,2,3');

Returno da consulta:
1

Retorno esperado da consulta:
1
2
3
```

Qual operador ou função pode ser usado neste caso?

Comment: Olá mcardoso, não sei se isso é o que você procura, mas acredito que você deveria mudar o ```IN('1,2,3')``` para ```IN(1,2,3)```, entendo que queira passar uma string no IN mas o ideal é usar itens do mesmo tipo da coluna, acredito que código seja um inteiro, neste caso o ideal seria passar os valores como inteiros separados por virgula.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve separar os itens na clausula `IN`, assim:

```
IN('1','2','3');
```

Ou:

```
SELECT codigo
FROM ccusto
WHERE ',1,2,3,' LIKE CONCAT('%,',codigo,',%');
```

Veja exemplo funcionando no [ideone](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b14115/2/0)